# Would creating directives for styling be considered an anti-pattern

Tags: css, angular, angular-directive

So I am in the process of creating a project-specific component UI library for a project that I'm working on. It requires specific stylized components and many of their elements are reused.

I'm noticing that I'm switching between the HTML template file and the style file quite a bit and repeating a lot of styling code boilerplate (similar CSS properties but differing values), and I thought perhaps I could 'angularize' the way I do styling by creating a custom directive which then either applies a CSS class pertaining to a fixed CSS style (like say an input field/button) or dynamically sets the style of the component using the renderer for commonly used properties but which have different values for specific components. Example below

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[SetWidth]'
})
export class SetWidthDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input('SetWidth') width: number | string = 'auto';

  @Input('Units') units?: 'px' | 'rem' | 'em' | '%';

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let style = '';

    if (typeof this.width == 'string') {
      style = this.width;
    } else {
      let u = this.units || 'px';
      style = `${this.width} ${u}`;
    }

    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el, 'width', style);
  }
}
```

Usage as follows:

```
<div [SetWidth]="100" Units="rem">Hello World</div>
```

I've made these for very helpful CSS styles such as height, display, template-grid-options,etc. With the customization that's afforded by directive classes, I am able to streamline a fair number of repetitive styling declarations.

My question is whether this would be considered an anti-pattern or bad practise. I'm not really concerned over whether it is the 'correct' way to do styling but rather whether this will have a significant impact on the performance/usability/etc of the application in general. It certainly improves the developer experience.

Comment: It's an anti pattern in the way that the styling is always overriding of any CSS. Also you can achieve almost the same result without using a directive, e.g. `[style.width.px]="100"` in your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it is an anti pattern to use directives for styling similar components infact it increases reusability and i think it is a good practice but if you want set only width then you should use inbuilt `style`directive.

also just a suggestion you don't need to use extra property for unit and check the type of `width` passed and `unit` passed. instead you can set the type of `width` property as string only pass that in `setStyle` function

also you can rename the `SetWidth` property to `width` only